# Не устанавливается delve

Tags: golang

Устанавливаю этот delve для работы с Go в VS Code.

```
go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
```

Появляется ошибка

```
# github.com/derekparker/delve/pkg/proc
D:\gowork\src\github.com\derekparker\delve\pkg\proc\disasm.go:11:14: undefined: ArchInst
```

Стоит Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: У вас винда x64?

Comment: Забыл добавить, что стоит Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: [32-bit не поддерживается.](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/20)

Comment: Плохо...
А есть какой-нить способ решения этой проблемы? Например, в liteide используется gdb. Можно ли как-то пристроить его в VS Code?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что решения на 32-битных системах нет. GDB с дефолтным компилятором работает [так-сяк](https://golang.org/doc/gdb). (Отмечу, что за пять лет работы с го, дебаггером почти не пользовался.)